# How to effective redraw bitmap?

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, android-bitmap

I have made a view that draws a square and in the middle has a "hole" that displays what is under it. It was also necessary to add animation of changing the size of this hole. Here is my implementation:

```
class RoundMaskView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr), SizeChangeListener {

    companion object {
        private const val SHIFT_COEF = 0.3f
    }

    init {
        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
    }

    private val squarePaint = Paint()
    private val squareBitmapPaint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
        color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.intro_color_background)
    }
    private val holeBitmapPaint = Paint().apply {
        isAntiAlias = true
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
    }
    private val holePaint = Paint().apply {
        xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT)
    }

    private var shift = 1f
    private val holeSquareSize = context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.item_intro_size)
        get() = (field * shift).toInt()
    private var squareBitmap: Bitmap? = null
    private var holeBitmap: Bitmap? = null

    override fun onSizeChange(progress: Float) {
        shift = 1f - SHIFT_COEF * progress
        resizeHoleBitmap()
        invalidate()
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        if (squareBitmap == null) {
            initBitmaps()
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(squareBitmap!!, 0f, 0f, squarePaint)
        canvas.drawBitmap(
            holeBitmap!!,
            (width / 2f) - holeSquareSize / 2f,
            (height / 2f) - holeSquareSize / 2f,
            holePaint
        )
    }

    private fun initBitmaps() {
        squareBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).apply {
            Canvas(this).drawRect(Rect(0, 0, width, height), squareBitmapPaint)
        }
        holeBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(holeSquareSize, holeSquareSize, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).apply {
            Canvas(this).drawCircle(holeSquareSize / 2f, holeSquareSize / 2f, holeSquareSize / 2f, holeBitmapPaint)
        }
    }

    private fun resizeHoleBitmap() {
        holeBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(holeSquareSize, holeSquareSize, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).apply {
            Canvas(this).drawCircle(holeSquareSize / 2f, holeSquareSize / 2f, holeSquareSize / 2f, holeBitmapPaint)
        }
    }
}
```

How you see when i call `onSizeChange(progress)` change size of hole (Bitmap). But after each call create new bitmap and i know is not perform effective. How to correct change size of bitmap for each calling `onSizeChange`?

Comment: if you want to drwa a "square with a hole in the middle" use `Canvas.drawPath(path, paint)` - where `path` is a `Path` object - pay attention on [FillType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.FillType.html)

Comment: @pskink you think we can do without the "complex" `xfermode = porterduffxfermode (porterduff.Mode.DST_OUT)` and `Bitmap`?

Comment: sure: draw a square [path](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path) with the hole in the middle

Comment: @pskink really. I change my solution and make it simple. Thx

Comment: sure, your welcome